# Pass data from Jade view to controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I have a *Submit* button in jade (code below):

```
p
    a(href='/commands/new')
    button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit')
        i.glyphicon.glyphicon-plus
        |           Add commands
```

which invokes the controller code:

```
router.get('/new', function(req, res) {    
    console.log("inside commands.js controller");
    // custom biz logic here...
    // need to get the value of the key passed to the controller when someone hits the "Add commands" button above
});
```

I want to pass some data to the controller when the *Add commands* button is pressed. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Communicating back from the client to the server needs ajax, assuming you don't want your page reloading.  Change the button to look like this:

```
button.btn.btn-primary(onclick='sendMessage()')
```

To send a message to that controller using [jquery's ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) add this to your template:

```
script.
  function sendMessage(){
    var xhr = $.ajax({
      "url": "/new?message=" + "(insert your message to the server here)",
      "method": "get"
    });

    xhr.done(function(data){
      // this runs when the request was successful and data is what the server sends back
    });

    xhr.fail(function(jqXhr, error){
      // this runs if the request failed
    });
  }
```

Then on your server you can read that "message" using `req.query.message`.